# how to sync the offline database with online database using an application built in adobe air

Tags: air

I am a newbie and would like to ask a question regarding adobe air.

My client wants an desktop based application. He wants the application to be run standalone on the machine of any user who has downloaded that application from his website.

He also requires that what so ever data that has  been stored in the desktop application can be synced with online database, if required.

i want to build the desktop application in adobe air.

Can you please guide me that how can i sync the offline and online data using an application built in adobe air?? Is it possible??

As i have studied that adobe air uses sqlite by defult, so do i have to use the same as server as well or can i  go with mysql also.
I am a newbie.

My client wants an desktop based application. He wants the application to be run standalone on the machine of any user who has downloaded that application from his website.

He also requires that what so ever data that has  been stored in the desktop application can be synced with online database, if required.

i want to build the desktop application in adobe air.

Can you please guide me that how can i sync the offline and online data using an application built in adobe air?? Is it possible??

As i have studied that adobe air uses sqlite by defult, so do i have to use the same as server as well or can i  go with mysql also.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you please guide me that how can i
>   sync the offline and online data using
>   an application built in adobe air?? Is
>   it possible??

Possible via URLRequest - send your desktop data to server handler (with POST method), then put it into database there. Handler is a page that can be created with any web technology - PHP, ASP.NET, Python, whatever.

> As i have studied that adobe air uses
>   sqlite by defult, so do i have to use
>   the same as server as well or can i go
>   with mysql also. I am a newbie.

You don't need to use same DB engine. All data needs to be transferred in intermediate format anyway. For format, I would choose XML - it has good support in AIR.